# A strange trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Today,in our class, we received a trigonometric equation

$$\sin^{10}{x}+\cos^{10}{x}=\frac{29}{16}\cos^4{2x}$$

and the question was to find the general solution of this equation. My approach was, at First, trying to show that there were no solutions using inequalities, but I failed. So, my last method was, expanding RHS by binomial theorem, and canceling some terms out, which at last gives a quadratic in $\sin{x}\cos{x}$. But this way was too long.

Can anyone suggest or give a simpler method? I firmly believe there's one trick in ques to make it easier, which I cannot solve.

Comment: Checking in Wolfram Alpha, the difference of both sides simplifies to something with a $cos(4x)$ factor which gives the roots. (The other factor happens to never vanish). But the trick is getting to that expression by hand, and that's not jumping out at me.

Comment: Setting $u = \cos^2 x$, one obtains an equivalent fourth-order polynomial equation in $u$, for which there is an explicit formula. But this probably isn't "easier".

Comment: yes, its more complicated, I suppose that just daring to solve by expanding LHS

Comment: Conversion to complex exponentials is usually helpful in cases like this. Here, the exponential form of $16\sin^{10} x + 16\cos^{10}x - 29 \cos^4 2x$ decomposes into straightforward factors.

Comment: sorry @Blue sir, I didn't get it properly. Can you please tell a bit more?

Comment: Using complex numbers, [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry) lets you write $$\sin x = \frac{1}{2ip}(p^2-1) \quad \cos x = \frac{1}{2p}(p^2+1) \quad \cos 2x = \frac{1}{2p^2}(p^4+1)$$ with $p = e^{ix}$. Expanding terms, collecting, and factoring gives $$\frac{1}{2p^8} ( p^8 + 1 ) ( 3 p^8 + 7 p^4 + 3 ) = 0$$ Solving this eqn is straightforward. However, you mention needing this "done in class"; the expand/collect/factor steps here are really too much to do by hand, so this approach is worse than your attempt and what other answers show.

Comment: Out of topic question, are you Dinesh on Brilliant.org?

Comment: Yes sir, @Tunk-Fey.

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$

Setting $\displaystyle\cos2x=u,$ we get $$\left(\frac{1-u}2\right)^5+\left(\frac{1+u}2\right)^5=\frac{29}{16}u^4$$

$$\iff2\left[1+\binom52u^2+\binom54u^4\right]=2^5\cdot\frac{29}{16}u^4$$

Again, $\displaystyle u^2=\frac{1+\cos4x}2$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sin^{10}x + \cos^{10}x = \frac{29}{16} \cos^4 2x $$

We can do some algebraic manipulation with the LHS in the following manner -

$$ \sin^{10}x + \cos^{10}x $$

$$\left(\frac{1- \cos 2x}{2}\right)^5 + \left(\frac{1+ \cos 2x}{2}\right)^5$$

$$ 2\times \frac{\left( \binom{5}{0} + \binom{5}{2} \cos^{2}2x + \binom{5}{4} \cos^4 2x \right)}{2^5}$$

Equate this to the RHS, and solve for the quadratic in $\cos^2 2x.$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $X^5+Y^5=(X+Y)(X^4-X^3Y+X^2Y^2-XY^3+Y^4)$; if we set $X=\sin^2x$ and $Y=\cos^2x$, the left hand side becomes
$$
(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)(\sin^8x-\sin^6x\cos^2x+\sin^4x\cos^4x-\sin^2x\cos^6x+\cos^8x)
$$
or
$$
\sin^8x+\cos^8x+\sin^4x\cos^4x-\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)
$$
The first three terms can be written
$$
(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)^2-\sin^4x\cos^4x
$$
and 
$$
\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x
$$
so we get
$$
(1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x)^2-\sin^4x\cos^4x-\sin^2x\cos^2x(1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x)
$$
which further simplifies into
$$
1-4\sin^2x\cos^2x+4\sin^4x\cos^4x-\sin^4x\cos^4x
-\sin^2x\cos^2x+2\sin^4x\cos^4x
$$
that is
$$
1-5\sin^2x\cos^2x+5\sin^4x\cos^4x
$$
or
$$
1-\frac{5}{4}\sin^2(2x)+\frac{5}{16}\sin^4(2x)
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: I had the same method, and as stated earlier in my ques, I too arrived at this quadratic in $\sin{x}\cos{x}$, but I felt that's too long to solve,

Comment: @Dinesh You can express $\cos^2(2x)$ in terms of $\sin^2(2x)$, can't you? This becomes a biquadratic in $\sin^2(2x)$.

Comment: Let me see if that biquadratic is solvable by easy means. Else, it wont give nice results.

Comment: @Dinesh I get $\sin^2(2x)=13/12$ (no solutions) or $\sin^2(2x)=1/2$. But check my computations.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%5E%2810%29%2Bcosx%5E%2810%29%3D29cos%5E4%282x%29%2F%2816%29

Comment: Well, a amazing thing to look at wolframalfa result is to see the first alternate form

Answer (score 0):

can this approach be somehow helpful? set $sin^2x=u$ and $cos^2x=1-u$ similar to what is suggested in one of the comments above. Then, after some manipulations the equations simplify to $$-\frac{(48a^2 - 48a + 13)\cdot(8a^2 - 8a + 1)}{16}=0$$ (I used matlab's symbolic toolbox to obtain this) whose ***real*** solutions are $$u=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}+\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$u=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
can you continue from here?

Comment: Well this ques was asked to be done in class,, so I dont think ur method would be much useful, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^{10}(x)=(1-\sin^2(x))^5$ and then factor
$\sin^{10}(x)+(1-\sin^2(x))^5-\frac{29}{16}(1-2\sin^2(x))^4$ to get
$$-\frac{1}{16}(48\sin(x)^4-48\sin(x)^2+13)(8\sin(x)^4-8\sin(x)^2+1)=0.$$ 
The first equation has no solutions since the discriminant is negative and the second has the solutions $\sin(x)=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ giving the solutions $\frac{k\pi}{8}, k=\pm 1, \pm 3$.